# I want to add/remove label dynamically in c sharp

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi Every One,
             I want to remove label dynamically, when check box unchecked the label should be deleted and when check box is checked then label should be added.
  Here is my code:-

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "customLabel";
    label.AutoSize = true;
    label.Text = "Dynamically Generated Label";
    label.Location = new Point(50, 50);
    label.BringToFront();
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    else
    {
        label.Visible = false;
        //this.Controls.Remove(label);
    }
}
```

but this code else statement is not working. Whenever I checked on check box then label created but whenever I unchecked check box then that label does not get removed. Someone help me Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: what would be the benefit of removing it instead of just hiding it as you are doing with `.Visible`? If you create it normally and just do `.Visible = true`, would that resolve the issue for you?

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want to create dynamically and remove that by using check box, that is my task. I know that it is simple if i take label from properties and just do .visible = true and .visible = false. But I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to just hide and show the label.

If you still want to add and remove it, you have to store a reference to it outside of your method, on the class. Otherwise you won't be able to remove it easily.

```
private Label label;  // field on the class (form)

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        label = new Label(); // instantiate new label
        label.Name = "customLabel";
        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Text = "Dynamically Generated Label";
        label.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        label.BringToFront();
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    else
    {
        if (label != null) // remove label
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(label);
            label = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulK. I agree but please see the wording of the question and comments below it. OP is aware that showing/hiding is easier but this is not what is required here.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not have a reference to the label added when checkbox was checked.

When you uncheck the checkbox, you dynamically created a new label, and then not showed it.
All previously created labels are not affected by your code...

You can add a reference to the label outside of the scope of function:

```
private Label label;  

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.label == null)   
    {
        label = new Label(); 
        label.Name = "customLabel";
        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Text = "Dynamically Generated Label";
        label.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        label.BringToFront();
    }

    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    else if(label != null && this.Controls.Contains(label))
    {

       this.Controls.Remove(label);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't hide the label that is visible to you, but rather create a new label, which is not added to the form (it would only be if the CheckBox was checked, but then it won't be hidden). The original label would be untouched and thus remain visible. After unchecking and checking several times there would be that much labals, hiding each other (only the topmost visible).

The easiest possibility Would be to just create the label with the form in the designer (let's call it lblDynamic) and then set lblDynamic.Visible to false in the Property editor (right click lblDynamic and then click "Properties").

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        lblDynamic.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblDynamic.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

Actually there is no need to create the label in your code, if the designer can do the work for you – at least in this scenario.